# PHP equivalent for jQuery $.extend()?

Tags: php, class, merge, extend

Is there anything equivalent in PHP for jQuery's $.extend()?

I want to pragmatically merge/combine/extend classes with other classes and it's properties (including methods) without using late static binding.

```
class a {}
class b {}
class c {}

$merged = combine(new a(), new b(), new c());
```

This is **not** what I am looking for:

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}

$merged = new b();
```

Comment: Back up a moment: _why_ would you want this? Even in modern JS this would be a pretty terrible idea, and you should write proper class relations instead. Just because we're now in PHP does not change that. What are you trying to achieve that makes you think you need this, because we're almost certainly looking at a case of [asking how to implement your imagined solution, rather than the real solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You're asking to do something very unusual - in JS, using Object.assign (the modern ES6 equivalent of extend/merge) with plain objects makes a lot of sense, but _not_ once they're class instances. At that point, something's almost certainly gone wrong and it's time to ask what someone is trying to achieve that they think they need Object.assign for. Similarly, you're asking about how to merge disparate class instances in PHP into a single thing: what are you trying to achieve that you think you need this for? Can you explain your use case in your post?

Comment: FYI, the answer to the question in your title is `array_merge()`. But there's no equivalent for class instances, and as @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans says, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: When you merge objects from different classes, which class prototype should they use?

Comment: Actually, it would be trivial to build such a thing, although I agree that I can't personally think of a reason for doing so. Create a function that returns a class. It could be a bare function, a constructor or a method. That class holds each item in an internal array, and you'd use the magic methods such as `__call` or reflection to pass through the wrapper class to the child. The algorithm for determining the child would be up to the implementation.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for replying to the topic. I don't have a concrete case where I had this in mind. I am researching my options for plugins and was inspired by how it was done in jQuery. array_merge() doesn't copy the methods unless they are anonymous functions. I don't think I will go down that road.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything equivalent in PHP, because their object systems are very different.

JavaScript doesn't have real classes like PHP does, its object system is based on prototypes. Methods can be direct properties of the instance, but if there isn't a direct property the prototype chain will be searched to find it. `$.extend()` automatically copies properties that are inherited from the prototype to the target object, so the result is kind of like an instance of a subclass of all the original classes.

But PHP doesn't have any equivalent to attaching methods directly to objects, so there's no way that a `combine()` function could merge all the methods from classes of the arguments. An object is an instance of a particular class, and it gets its methods from the class object (and its superclasses) only.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Barmar said, this isn't really a thing in PHP. Workarounds are ugly but I am going to describe two ugly workarounds for whoever want a big laugh.

**Workaround #1** - Extend classes by the use of magic methods in a class. Pros are that the properties and methods can be accessed from one merged object. But under the surface they are not really merged. So setting properties is discouraged and cross accessing properties is a no go.

```
class extend {
  private $_objects;
  private $_properties = [];

  public function __construct(...$objects) {
    $this->_objects =  array_reverse($objects);
  }

  public function &__isset($name) {
    return $this->__get($name);
  }

  public function __get($name) {

    foreach ($this->_objects as $object) {
      if (isset($object->$name)) {
        return $object->$name;
      }
    }

    if (isset($this->_properties[$name])) {
      return $this->_properties[$name];
    }

    return null;
  }

   public function __set($name, $value) {

    foreach ($this->_objects as $object) {
      if (isset($object->$name)) {
        $object->$name = $value;
        return true;
      }
    }

    $this->_properties[$name] = $value;

    return true;
  }

  public function __call($name, $params) {

    foreach ($this->_objects as $object) {
      if (method_exists($object, $name)) {
        call_user_func_array([$object, $name], $params);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Example Objects:

```
class a {
  var $fruit= 'apple';
  function foo() { return 'a'; }
}

class b {
  var $fruit = 'banana';
  function bar() { return 'b'; }
}
```

Merge Example:

```
$merged = new extend(new a(), new b());
echo $merged->foo();
echo $merged->bar();

$merged->this = 'that';
echo $merged->this;
```

**Workaround #2** - Merging objects with anonymous functions instead of methods makes them portable and mergeable. Cons are it may be considered unethic or a future security risk to rely on them.
Anonymous functions in properties can not be defined in the class, but must be set in __construct(). And accessing anonymous functions as properties conflicts the syntax for calling regular methods. So a workaround for the calling syntax is also needed (PHP 7.0+).

Example Objects:

```
class a {
  var $fruit = 'apple';

  function __construct(){
    $this->foo = function() { return 'a'; };
  }
}

class b {
  var $fruit = 'banana';

  function __construct() {
    $this->bar = function() { return 'b'; };
  }
}
```

Merge Example:

```
$merged = (object)array_merge(
  get_object_vars(new a()),
  get_object_vars(new b())
);

echo ($merged->foo)(); // $class->var() doesn't work for anonymous functions
echo ($merged->bar)();

$merged->fruit = 'orange';
echo $merged->fruit;
```

**Final conclusions:** Surely unconventional, mostly ugly.

You might be better off with late static bindings for extending PHP class objects.

```
class a {}
class b extends a {}
class c extends b {}
```